# Renaming tag "findall-prolog" to "prolog-findall"

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request

A while ago, the new [prolog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/prolog) specific tag [findall-prolog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/findall-prolog) was introduced.

In principle having a tag about the "all-solutions" Prolog predicate(s) `findall/[3,4]` is a Good Thing.

A number of Prolog SO-questions had had the tag [findall](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/findall). That tag which is about a Python function—and is not related to Prolog.

Retagging these questions to [findall-prolog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/findall-prolog)  tag is a step forward, but the concrete choice [findall-prolog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/findall-prolog) is unfortunate as it is not consistent with other long established Prolog-related tags:

- "All-solution" predicate `setof/3` has a dedicated tag: [prolog-setof](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/prolog-setof).
- The tag names [swi-prolog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swi-prolog), [sicstus-prolog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sicstus-prolog), and [b-prolog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/b-prolog) use "prolog" as a suffix, not a prefix.

So why not replace [findall-prolog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/findall-prolog) with [prolog-findall](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/prolog-findall) to improve consistency?

Remarks? Opinions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[findall-prolog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/findall-prolog) has been renamed and syn'd to [prolog-findall](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/prolog-findall).